# Struts 2 not setting action property on form submission. Unexpected Exception caught .Error setting expression with value ['1', ]

Tags: hibernate, struts2, struts, ognl

Struts 2  is giving a strange behavior that the commercial,productCategory objects is not set on on form submission.It happens in some cases like these.Other fields are getting set properly

Most of the cases struts 2 is setting the custom objects very well and even for complex objects like List inside a object but in this case it is giving strange behavior.

Can somebody help in this.Can i debug the struts 2 code to check why it is not setting the property.If possible let me know the steps

Hibernate domain object:

```
public class Brand {            
    private Long id;                
    private String brandName;               
    private String brandDescription;                
    private Brand productSubCategory;               
    private ProductCategory productCategory;                
    private CommercialType commercial;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

JSP:

```
<s:select label = "Commercial Type" 
           name = "brand.commercial.id" 
           list = "#attr.masterData.commercialTypes" 
        listKey = "id" 
      listValue = "commercialType" 
          value = "%{brand.commercial.id}" 
          theme = "simple" 
      headerKey = "" 
    headerValue = "--Select--" 
/>
```

Comment: Do you get errors or it just doesn't set the value correctly? Are those fields pointing to instances of those classes or are they `null`?

Comment: It does n't just set the property commercial.No error. commercial is null."brand.commercial.id" value does not set.

Comment: Here is the exception with devmode true.                                                            Unexpected Exception caught setting 'brand.commercial.id'  Error setting expression 'brand.commercial.id' with value ['1', ]

Comment: If `commercial` is null then you either need to store the object in the session scope, rather than request, or initialise the `commercial` field with an instance of the `CommercialType` class when you declare it. The former sounds like the correct route, to be honest, but it depends what you're doing with it. You can't set a field on a field that doesn't reference anything.

Comment: Thanks Anthony Grist.latter worked fine.I created the instance of child objects inside constructor of parent constructor.But I still wonder why this strange behavior.In most of the cases it works fine

Comment: For curiosity, can you post `CommercialType` complete code (constructors, getters and setters too) ?

Answer (score 0):

***Answer based on the first look***

I didn't find any error in the code that you have posted. But according to the Error which its generated in the dev mode, My thoughts roam around this.

**Error**

`Unexpected Exception caught setting 'brand.commercial.id' Error setting expression 'brand.commercial.id' with value ['1', ]`

**Possible reason**

The `brand.commercial.id` is used as the name variable in two or more places in the same form . if the same variable is set twice in the same name, the struts will consider that as a list which makes this `['1', ] ,assuming the brand.commercial.id is not a list.

Other possibility is that, some list value is set to the integer value.